# javascript force next input if condition meet

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm currently using jQuery [liveform validation](http://livevalidation.com/) plugin to validate the input column if condition is meet and I use below code to force next if the input button reach the max input.

```
window.onload=function(){
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
    container.onkeyup = function(e) {
        var target = e.srcElement;
        var maxLength = parseInt(target.attributes["maxlength"].value, 10);
        var myLength = target.value.length;
        if (myLength >= maxLength) {
            var next = target;
            while (next = next.nextElementSibling) {
                if (next == null)
                    break;
                if (next.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input") {
                    next.focus();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my form code:

```
    <span class="label">Date:</span> <input type="text" id="f1" name="day" maxlength="2" placeholder="DD" /><br /><br />            
    <span class="label">Month:</span> <input type="text" id="f2" name="month" maxlength="2" placeholder="MM" /><br /><br />
    <span class="label">Year:</span> <input type="text" id="f3" name="year" maxlength="4" placeholder="YYYY" /><br /><br />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    // Validate day column:
    var f1 = new LiveValidation('f1');
    f1.add( Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 1, maximum: 31 } );
    // Validate month column:
    var f2 = new LiveValidation('f2');
    f2.add( Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 1, maximum: 12 } );
    // Validate year column:
    var f3 = new LiveValidation('f3');
    f3.add( Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 1940, maximum: 2021 } );
    //]]>
    </script>
```

The problem I have is, for example if day (f1) input I enter 33 which is not valid the javascript will auto next to monh (f2) input and so on.

**My question is:** Is it possible to change the javascript to only force next if the condition is meet? For example, if input day (f1) data within 1 to 31, it force to next input else if data out of the range it will **not** force next input and clear the (f1) input box.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TGeKS/)

Comment: I am not sure this code is actually working. Can you provide a live example like a jsFiddle ?

Comment: See http://www.mathachew.com/sandbox/jquery-autotab/

Comment: @MilchePatern I added the demo in first post, but somehow the input force next is not working but the code work in my localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TGeKS/3/

```
//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
    container.onkeyup = function(e) {
        var target = e.srcElement;
        var maxLength = parseInt(target.attributes["maxlength"].value, 10);
        var myLength = target.value.length;
        if (myLength >= maxLength) {
            var next = target;
            while (next = next.nextElementSibling) {
                if (next == null)
                    break;
                if (next.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input") {
                    next.focus();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// Validate day column:
var f1 = new LiveValidation('f1', {
    wait: 750,
    onValid: function() {
        this.insertMessage( this.createMessageSpan() ); this.addFieldClass();
        document.getElementById("f2").focus();
    }
});
f1.add(Validate.Numericality, {
    minimum: 1,
    maximum: 31
});
// Validate month column:
var f2 = new LiveValidation('f2', {
        wait: 750,
        onValid: function() {
            this.insertMessage( this.createMessageSpan() ); this.addFieldClass();
            document.getElementById("f3").focus();
        }
    });
f2.add(Validate.Numericality, {
    minimum: 1,
    maximum: 12
});
// Validate year column:
var f3 = new LiveValidation('f3');
f3.add(Validate.Numericality, {
    minimum: 1940,
    maximum: 2021
});
//]]>
```

Idea: As mentioned in the documentation, here http://livevalidation.com/documentation#LiveValidation , We can define object and pass custom function in onValid property. But there is one gotcha, LiveValidation is firing onValid event on every keystroke like "1" & "2" in "12" so there is one more helpful option called "wait" which is set to "750" in milliseconds, you can fine tune it if required.

Comment: thanks man! it works! just a question, is it possible to clear the input box if the data enter is wrong? for example (f2) allow 1-12. if the user enter 14, then after the wait period it clear the input box.

Comment: I think, yes, as there is one parameter called "onInvalid" as mentioned in documentation which can be used to accomplish the task of clearing the input field. It is similar to the onValid option/event as explained in above comment.